# Many to Many join with fact and dim table in Spark 3?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two data frames one with 10M records and the other with 100K records.

Let's say the schema of the first data frame

```sql
create table fact_table
(
    id      string,
    dim_id_list ARRAY<string>
);
```

where `dim_id_list` is an array with a length of `1-200`.

and the fact table

```sql
create table dim_table
(
    id      string,
    tag     string
)
```

where 80K+ ids can have the same tag

example random data
fact_table

```
id |  dim_id_list
----------------------
1  | [a, b]
2  | [a, b, c]
3  | [a, b, c, d]
4  | [a, b, c, d, e]
5  | [a, b, c, d, e, f]
....
```

dim table

```
id |      tag
----------------------
a  |     john            
b  |     foo          
c  |     foo          
d  |     foo          
f  |     foo          
g  |     bar          
h  |     random          
i  |     spark          
.......
```

What I want to do is add unique tags to the fact table, as shown in the output

output:

```
id |  dim_id_list       |   tag
---------------------------------
1  | [a, b]             |   john
1  | [a, b]             |   foo
2  | [a, b, c]          |   john
2  | [a, b, c]          |   foo
3  | [a, b, c, d]       |   john 
3  | [a, b, c, d]       |   foo 
4  | [a, b, c, d, e]    |   john      
4  | [a, b, c, d, e]    |   foo      
4  | [a, b, c, d, e]    |   random      
5  | [a, b, c, d, e, f] |   john         
5  | [a, b, c, d, e, f] |   foo         
5  | [a, b, c, d, e, f] |   random         
5  | [a, b, c, d, e, f] |   bar   
.....
```

basically a left join but with unique tags

the query I wrote for this is

```sql
select fact_table.id, dim_id_list, tag
from fact_table
         left join (select collect_list(id) as id_list,
                           tag
                    from dim_table
                    group by tag) as dim_table
                   on arrays_overlap(fact_table.dim_id_list, dim_table.id_list);
```

spark scala equivalent:

```
val dimDf_agg = dimDf
    .groupBy("tag")
    .agg(collect_set("id")
    .as("id_list"))

val join_df = fact_df(broadcast(dimDf_agg),
                      arrays_overlap(fact_df("dim_id_list"), 
                      dimDf_agg("id_list")), "left")
              .drop("id_list")
```

but here it becomes so complex to execute as the complexity of `array_overlap` is very high.

Is there a more optimized approach that I can follow?

Something like doing broadcast join (left) with the hash of `id_list` and `dim_id_list` and just taking the first 'foo' or something else?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is explode the array (so as to generate one row per item in `dim_id_list`) and then join over that value. Then you can use distinct to remove the duplicates.

```scala
// simply generating the data for reproducibility
val fact_df = Seq(
    1 -> Seq("a","b"),
    2 -> Seq("a","b","c"),
    3 -> Seq("a","b","c","d"),
    4 -> Seq("a","b","c","d","e"),
    5 -> Seq("a","b","c","d","e","f")
).toDF("id", "dim_id_list")

val dim_df = Seq(
    "a" -> "john",            
    "b" -> "foo",          
    "c" -> "foo",         
    "d" -> "foo",         
    "f" -> "foo",         
    "g" -> "bar",         
    "h" -> "random",          
    "i" -> "spark"  
).toDF("id", "tag")
```

And the solution:

```scala
fact_df
    .withColumn("id_tag", explode('dim_id_list))
    .join(dim_df.select('id as "id_tag", 'tag), Seq("id_tag"))
    .drop("id_tag")
    .distinct
    .orderBy("id")
    .show
```

```
+---+------------------+----+
| id|       dim_id_list| tag|
+---+------------------+----+
|  1|            [a, b]|john|
|  1|            [a, b]| foo|
|  2|         [a, b, c]|john|
|  2|         [a, b, c]| foo|
|  3|      [a, b, c, d]|john|
|  3|      [a, b, c, d]| foo|
|  4|   [a, b, c, d, e]| foo|
|  4|   [a, b, c, d, e]|john|
|  5|[a, b, c, d, e, f]|john|
|  5|[a, b, c, d, e, f]| foo|
+---+------------------+----+
```

Comment: won't it increase the complexity?

Comment: in the dataframe every list have 2 or 3 same tags then that 10M records will turn into 20-40M isn't it?

Comment: With `array_overlap`, a record of `fact_df` is going to be tested against every single element of `dim_df`. That's expensive. Here, using a regular join you will avoid those comparisons. Note that you can still broadcast `dim_df` here. But try it and let me know if it improves the performance.

Comment: Have you found the answer to your problem?

Comment: nope, I am just using array_overlap way mentioned in the problem right now.